# Higher age restriction for a specific in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

Ive just submitted an app to the AppStore. Now I want to add some in-app purchases. Is it possible to add 18+ restricted in-app purchases for an app rated 4+?

Comment: If you provide a content, which is 18+ I would assume that the app needs to be rated with 18+ instead of 4+...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the App Store Review Guidelines say:

> 2.3.6 Answer the age rating questions in iTunes Connect honestly so that your app aligns properly with parental controls. If your app is mis-rated, customers might be surprised by what they get, or it could trigger an inquiry from government regulators.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#accurate-metadata

If your app in any special case shows content aged for 18+ the app store age rating should be 18+.